# DD-WRT bridging mode

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

I have my Ubuntu Server, providing internet to home LAN. I want to connect DD-WRT router to my server in bridging mode, so wireless devices can get IP from server. Basically I want DD-WRT router to act like bridge. I read Wiki but still not clear. All I found is how to connect 2 routers to extend range, which isn't what I want.

So the question is how to configure DD-WRT in proper bridging mode?

Comment: You may simply disable DHCP and use LAN port instead of WAN.

Comment: This will not pass through the traffic. I have to set router into bridging mode.

Comment: Usualy Wlan and lan interfaces are bridged by default, so it should work. You may find out, if that is your case on `Setup -> Networking` in web interface. Why do you think it'll not pass the traffic?

Comment: Why do you want to use a router at all? With hostapd, you can use your PC's wireless card to provide an AP to your wireless clients. That it automatically bridged with your ethernet connection, and you may save the money of a router, or use it elsewhere as a repeater, for instance.

Comment: @Marius Matutiae: I already have that router with DD-WRT with much better coverage than I could get with card Wi-Fi and I don't have wireless card. Also Wireless router is more mobile, can place anywhere near server...

Comment: Ok. Bu then week has already told you the solution. Connect the WAN side of the router to your server, turn off DHCP/dnsmasq and you are done. In any router, ethernet and wireless interfaces are hardware-bridged, there is no need to do it via software, it is faster too.

Comment: eth0/eth2 are bridged. But when I connect wireless device, still I got IP from router, not server, even though I have disabled DHCP on router. Wireless configuration have several modes - AP, Client, Client Bridged, Repeater, Repeater Bridged, AdHoc. I'm sure this also need to be changed.

Comment: How do you know you get an IP from the disabled DHCP from the DD-WRT? Is that IP in the same range as your server? It could be your client is still using the old IP.

Comment: @Rik, because the IP range is from router configuration. My server has different IP range.

Comment: As long as your WiFi-client can ping its previous default gateway and its DHCP-lease is not yet expired (or halfway through) it will try to use the previous IP-configuration (which it can because the previous gateway was the DD-WRT). Only when doing a `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` it will search for a new DHCP-server. Did you do a `ipconfig /release`?

Comment: @Rik see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution I came up with.

I changed mode to **Router** instead of **Gateway**

[image]

Then set router IP to my server's subnet IP and disabled DHCP.

[image]

At this point my wireless clients are able to get IP from server. Not sure if this is complete and perfect solution but one may use it.

Comment: Are you using the WAN-port at this moment? Then the "Router" setting is the correct one. See [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/help/english/HRouting.asp) (look at "Operating Mode"). If you would have used "Gateway" (which is default) you couldn't use the WAN-port because that one is "Natted". The other ports not. You *could* have used a LAN-port to the server in "Gateway" mode and DHCP disabled. But this setting is probably the best in this setup.

Comment: @Rik No, I'm not using WAN port. It's acting like switch. I've updated first screenshot to show that I set Interface to Both. Not sure what is it, but looks like it is switching WAN to act like LAN.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) is an article to set the DD-WRT as "Wireless access point". Its setup is the same as yours except it doesn't mention the "Dynamic Routing" so i'm not sure you need to set it different then the default. It does mention other settings (like optional DNSMasq to Disable and disabling the firewall). You could check if these settings correspond with yours. The method we mentioned was the "Simple version" on that page. You could look at all the settings in the "Long version".

Comment: @Rik Yes I've seen this article but it was mentioning Primary/Secondary routers so I thought it's for range extension. I only have 1 router.

Comment: Well... you could see your "Ubuntu Server" as a "router". It provides IP/DHCP and routing/NAT. So the DD-WRT wouldn't know any better as if it's a router or server.

Comment: I see. +1 for bringing my attention again to that article. Indeed there are steps I may do in order to have complete configuration.